# Building drone transceiver module with 2 recievers onboard to switch gates ON/OFF to turn motors On/Off

Tags: circuits, wireless-communication, rf-electronics, circuit-design

[image: Transceiver circuit module]

I'm looking for any resource that can help me build a radio (no infrared) controlled circuit with two receivers onboard a drone. The purpose of this circuit is for research and education. Whenever transmitter sends :

1. a signal to receiver 1, the receiver 1 circuit module should close switch a, and
2. a signal to receiver 2 module, it should open switch B (which is normally closed)
   A) How can I differentiate between the two received signals so that there is no false switching ?
   B) Which module will work best with low weight & long range as primary objective ?
   If anyone knows where I can get parts for such transceiver RF circuits or even a tutorial or schematic that would be really appreciated.

I'm looking for is something to get me started in the right direction to build RF wireless circuits or use an available module. Thanks!

Comment: this sounds like one for the [EE stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) forum

Comment: To get started I would look at 433 MHz RF modules. They are pretty cheap and abundant. Long term you might need something better.

Comment: Thanks Mahendra